# Declaring a variable dynamically

Tags: c#, backend, code-organization

I have a simple structure of the users like this:

```
public Guest() : IUser
{
}

[Table("Users")]
public class Customer : Guest
{
    [Key]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get;protected set; }
    public UserCart UserCart { get; private set; }

    public Customer()
    {

    }

    public Customer(string username, string password, string address)
    {
        this.Address = address;
        this.UserName = username;
        this.Password = password;
        this.IsAdmin = false;
        this.UserCart = new UserCart();
    }
}

public class Admin : Customer
{
    public Admin()
    {

    }

    public Admin(string username, string password, 
        string address) 
        : base(username, password, address)
    {
        IsAdmin = true;

    }
}
```

The inheritance is based on *Actions* they can do. The system will have to work differently depending on who uses it.

Admins can browse and buy and mess around with the orders and goods.

Customers can browse and buy.

Guests can browse only (and login/reg of course).

To know who's our current user, we need a property or field inside our `Authentication class` that is `IUser`, so anyone, an Admin, a Customer and a Guest can also be instantiated in it. 
Problem is, when I have only this IUser, when I instantiate, I can do basically nothing.

So the question: I want to load that field or property and I still want to access the functionalities of it - but only those that the given user can, so if an Admin logged in, I want to do the admin's job. If a Customer logged in, I want only to be able to list the goods and so on. How to do this?

**EDIT:** trying with reflection

```
public class Guest : IUser
    {
        public Guest()
        {

        }

        public object Get()
        {
            Type type = this.GetType();
            var result = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

That `Get()` method gives only an `object` but if it is called by a `Guest`, it has to be Guest. If called by an `Admin`, it has to be Admin. 
I could do this using overrides, but it's hard to modify later on.

So I wish this:

```
(MyObject)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Where `MyObject` is a Guest if called from a Guest, Admin if called from an admin. What am I missing? of course I tried generics, but that expects a concrete type when I'm implementing the interface, so basically I need to implement this in all my descendant classes.

Comment: if you want to use this scheme for your case, as you already pointed out, does not work out. You need to change the way the classes inherit. Don't you think so? i think `IUser` needs a public method `Login`

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. 
This isn't only up to me, and there are a whole bunch of other methods, i just wanted to keep it simple here. 
What I though of, I shall use `reflection` in a method defined in `IUser`, say a `Get()` that will return the actual type of the variable. Doable?

Comment: I already use this in some the games we produce. Basically, we have `Monster` class and `User` class, which are derived from `Unit`. I have a method `GetUnitType()` defiend in base class. It is pretty fast too :)

Comment: Glad we thought of the same thing. 
Could you tell me how you do it there? It's obvious to use if-elseif and so on fr my classes but I need something versatile and all I can do now is use `Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfMyObject)`, but then I would have to cast it to my type. Or should I override this `Get()` in all my classes?

Comment: *“Problem is, when I have only this IUser, when I instantiate, I can do basically nothing.”* – What do those user types have in common? That’s what should be inside the common interface. If they don’t have anything in common, then maybe they don’t share the same base type after all.

Comment: They will have a couple of things in common, those are to be implemented. I described what I wish, that I want an IUser to use as all my classes and that's the question. I updated it and added what I tried.

Comment: By the way, @poke, is it clear what I wish to do? I admit the question is full of mambo-jambo so if you want me to clarify, please ask away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what we talked in the comments, here is a direct copy paste form our server-side game code. But a reminder to keep in mind: If you define `IUser` interface but always cast it into appropriate class later like `var customer = iUser as Customer`. you may be on the wrong path. We use the below code only on a few occasions.

```
public void DoSomethingWithBattleUnit(BattleUnit bUnit){
    if(bUnit.UnitType==typeof(BattleMonster)){
    var bMonster = bUnit as BattleMonster;
    bMonster.ActivateAI();
}


public abstract class BattleUnit {
    public abstract Type UnitType { get; }
}

public class BattleMonster : BattleUnit {
    /// <summary>
    /// Current type for this class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Micro optimization instead of using this.GetType() or calling typeof(BattleMonster) each time.</remarks>
    static readonly Type Type = typeof(BattleMonster);

    public override Type UnitType => Type;
}

public class BattleUser : BattleUnit, IUser {

    /// <summary>
    /// Current type for this class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Micro optimization instead of using this.GetType() or calling typeof(BattleUser) each time.</remarks>
    private static readonly Type Type = typeof(BattleUser);

    public override Type UnitType => Type;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I can't make out of this is how would I instantiate from this? 
I update my question with some code I'm trying, just a moment...

Comment: Why do you do this? I don’t get why an instance should have a member that additionally says what type it is. Are you doing `if (someUnit.UnitType == typeof(BattleMonster))` in places then? Don’t do that. Just do `if (someUnit is BattleMonster)` instead. Objects already have an actual type.

Comment: @poke yes we exactly do that `if (someUnit.UnitType == typeof(BattleMonster))` in some rare cases. There are rarely any cases to use `is` because it does a cast and, in most cases, you end up casting the variable anyway.

Comment: `is` does *not* cast the variable. And if you’re going to cast it *anyway*, then you should just do a type conversion with `as` and check for `null`. Or use the [new pattern variables with `is` in C#7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#user-content-pattern-matching).

Comment: And btw., your `obj.UnitType` property is just a fragile way of doing `obj.GetType()`. You are adding a lot of boilerplate code there that will actively cause harm sooner than later. It depends too much on humans remembering to implement it properly, and has a lot of implications on the whole inheritance. Just think about having a subtype of `BattleMonster` now (just some special one): Not only do developers need to remember to actively overwrite the property, you also have to change every logic that expects just a *normal* `BattleMonster` instead of using inheritance here to accept any kind.

Comment: @poke Please look at the ILCode for `is` before giving false information such as saying it does not cast variable. It DOES in fact CAST if you look at the generated ILCode :) `is` and `as` both uses `isinst`. If you use `is`, you are doing casting twice. One is implicitly done by the compiler, one is explicitly done by the author. We are well aware of the problems it introduces. Unfortunately, time problems strike hard :P. C#7 is out of question.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible and not even that hard.

**SOLUTION 1: the `dynamic` keyword**

I have this interface `IUser` and a property in it

```
public interface IUser
{
    dynamic Instance { get; }
}
```

And I implement it **only in the ancestor**, in my case the Guest:

```
public class Guest : IUser
{
    public Guest()
    {

    }

    public dynamic Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

This way I can just declare an `IUser` like so in the Program.cs:

```
 IUser user = new Admin("wat", "asd", 012);
 Console.WriteLine(user.Instance.PW);
```

And I get the password that is "asd".

**Mayor drawback:**

I'm unable to use Intellisense because of the dynamic.

**SOLUTION 2: USING EXTENSION METHODS**

This one is a bit uglier both to implement and to use, but one can still harness the power of Intellisense.

So here we have this fine Extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T Get<T>(this T input) where T:class
    {
        Type t = input.GetType();
        MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Get");
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(t);
        return (T)generic.Invoke(input,null);
    }
}
```

This requires all the classes to have a `Get` method.
In my case I shall define it in my IUser interface like so:

```
public interface IUser
{
    T Get<T>() where T : class;
}
```

T has to be a class if I am to use the `as` keyword later on.

And the implementation of `Get` in my Guest is like

```
public T Get<T>() where T:class
{
     var _instance = this;
     return _instance as T;
}
```

Of course it doesn't require the descendants to implement `Get` again.

Once complete we can get the current type:

```
 IUser adm = new Admin("wut", "mehpw", 1000);
 var stuff = adm.Get<Admin>().Name;
```

**Drawbacks:**

I do have to know the type of the object I'm using, so basically this isn't more than using

```
var stuff = (adm as Admin).Name;
```

So hardly any edges here.

I could think of basically loading a class with the given property values but that wouldn't be the same reference as my created `IUser` and would certainly be **very** slow.